# Regarding different results for random forest using R

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I fitted the random forest model where the number number of variables at each split,  `mtry` was found using cross validation by caret package. My code is as follows,

```
require(ISLR)
require(caret)
set.seed(123)
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",number = 5,savePredictions = T)
mod_fit <- train(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Lag5 + Volume,
                 data=Smarket, method = "rf", 
                 trControl = fitControl,tuneLength  =5,ntree=1000)



 > mod_fit$bestTune
  mtry
1    2
>
```

I obtained final model using all the data and `mtry` = 2 as follows,

```
> mod_fit$finalModel

Call:
 randomForest(x = x, y = y, ntree = 1000, mtry = param$mtry) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 1000
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 50.48%
Confusion matrix:
     Down  Up class.error
Down  265 337   0.5598007
Up    294 354   0.4537037
```

But when i fit the same model with mtry=2 for the entire data using randomforest package , i am getting a different result

```
require(randomForest)
set.seed(123)
rf <- randomForest(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Lag5 + 
                     Volume, data = Smarket,  
                           mtry = 2, ntree = 1000, importance = TRUE)


    > rf

    Call:
     randomForest(formula = Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + 
Lag3 + Lag4 +      Lag5 + Volume,
 data = Smarket, mtry = 2, ntree = 1000, importance = TRUE) 
                   Type of random forest: classification
                         Number of trees: 1000
    No. of variables tried at each split: 2

            OOB estimate of  error rate: 49.84%
    Confusion matrix:
         Down  Up class.error
    Down  270 332   0.5514950
    Up    291 357   0.4490741
```

What may be the reason for the different results ?

Also when i used to predict function , i am getting following results which says there is no error in classification.

```
> rfPredict1 <- predict(mod_fit,newdata = Smarket )
> caret::confusionMatrix(rfPredict1, Smarket$Direction  )
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction Down  Up
      Down  602   0
      Up      0 648

               Accuracy : 1          
                 95% CI : (0.9971, 1)
    No Information Rate : 0.5184     
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16  

                  Kappa : 1          

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA         

            Sensitivity : 1.0000     
            Specificity : 1.0000     
         Pos Pred Value : 1.0000     
         Neg Pred Value : 1.0000     
             Prevalence : 0.4816     
         Detection Rate : 0.4816     
   Detection Prevalence : 0.4816     
      Balanced Accuracy : 1.0000     

       'Positive' Class : Down
```

What did i do wrong here ? Thanks

Comment: Random forests are *random*, you will get slightly different results each time you fit them. `caret` reports "out of bag" error, error for cases that weren't in the training data, whereas when you predict you're predicting on the same data you trained on I think, so you're getting perfect accuracy (due to overfitting).

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment. But if i used a seed value then shouldnt i get the same results ?

Comment: No, because `caret` would be fitting models to each of the CV splits first before fitting that final model, so the random number generator is being used before it's fit. You'll only get the same results if both models are fit right after the seed is set.